# Read pipe from another .c with use of exec, c programm

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe

i have a problem reading from a pipe that was created from another .c via execl! I have tried it with a lot of different approaches but i still can't find the solution. I'd appreciate it if you could help me!

Here is the first code :

...some other code before for loop...

```
for (counter=0; counter<arithmos; counter++)
   {
       if (pipe(pinakas[counter]) == -1)
       {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(1);
       }
       sem_wait(&sima);
       strcpy(buffer,queueHead(q));
       write(fd[WRITE], buffer, strlen(buffer));
       queueRemove(&q);
       nodes--;
       sem_post(&sima);
       pid = fork();
       if (pid < 0)
       {
           perror("fork error");
           exit(1);
       }
       if (pid == 0)
       {
            execl("./paidi","paidi", (char*)pinakas[counter], (char*)NULL);
            exit(1);
       }
       if (pid > 0)
       {

          printf ("I am the parent with pid %d\n", getpid());
          wait(NULL);

       }
   }
```

And here is what my child does...

includes etc etc...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    //char fd[2];
    int *fd = (int*) argv[1];
    int nbytes;
    char buffer[256];
    char *command;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = '\0';
    }

    printf("test2 %d\n",fd[READ]);
    //close(fd[WRITE]);
    printf("test3\n");
    read(fd[READ], buffer, 256);
    printf("test4\n");
    close(fd[READ]);
    printf("test5\n");
    printf("Received url : %s", buffer );
    printf("test6\n");
    //sprintf(command,"wget %zd", url);
    //system(command);
    printf("I am a child with pid %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Seems like i am doing something wrong with execl. I am trying to pass pointer as argument and i have a pipe : bad address error. I also tried it with string but nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: `pipe(pinakas[counter])` does that even compile?

Comment: You can't pass pointers between processes.  You shouldn't try passing integers as strings in the command arguments to `execv()` (convert the value to a string and pass the string).  You need to close the unused ends of the pipe in parent and child.  It is not clear from the code why you're using pipes since the parent neither sends anything to the child nor reads anything back from the child.  It is not clear why you have the semaphore operations in there either, but we can assume they are relevant to some other part of the homework.

Comment: i am sending using write...! my pipes are named fd and pinakas[] is an array with many fd's, so i am passing with exec the specific pipe that i need

Comment: If the parent is writing to the child, the parent must close the read end of the pipe, and the child must close the write end of the pipe, or vice versa if the parent is reading from the child.  Failing to do that leads to 'no EOF detected' until the writing process exits or the write end of the pipe is closed by `close()` or equivalent.  When plumbing between processes, you need to be sure you've accounted for all the file descriptors.  If you redirect the pipe to standard input or standard output, then you close both ends of the pipe itself.

Comment: "pinakas[] is an array with many fd's" -- so you pass a single integer (probably zero) to `pipe` rather than a pointer to an array of two integers. Again, I'm surprised this compiles at all, but even regardless of `execve` (see Nikolai N Fetissov's answer), I see no way how the call to `pipe` could _not_ fail.

Answer (score 2):

[`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) creates a brand-new memory space for loaded executable, you cannot pass pointers from previous program, they don't make any sense in that new memory space.

The tried and true approach here is to replace child's standard input (file descriptor 0) with read-end of the [`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) after the [`fork(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) but before the [`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) using [`dup2(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html).

Comment: Right, though your description of the problem isn't 100% accurate. He doesn't pass a pointer, but an integer disguised as one. `execl` expects pointers to NULL-terminated strings, which it copies elsewhere and provides a pointer to the copy. So the original pointer value isn't kept.

Comment: @ugoren, you are right. My eyes just hurt too much looking at that code :)